# Equating returned data in ajax call with array values in JS function

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax

I'm trying to figure out how to equate/compare values from returned data in an ajax call with an already established array

I have an `itemArray` containing 'category' and 'color' and then my ajax call returns a multilevel array that also has a 'type' which contains an array with levels of category and color as well

I'm simply trying to figure out how to take the ajax returned data and simply say "if category in returned data matches category from itemArray, then result = true"

```
  var itemArray = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($items);?>');
  //this contains items called 'category' and 'color'

  //console.log(itemArray);
  var code = document.getElementById("code").value;
  $.ajax({
       type:'POST',
       url:'validate',
       data:{code:code},
        _token: '{{ csrf_token() }}',
        success: function(data){
          console.log(data);

          // this dumps an object with the following structure
          /*
                ID
                    name
                        type:array
                            0
                                category
                                color
                            1
                                category
                                color
            */

        }
    });

for(var i =0; i < itemArray.length; i++){
    var obj = itemArray[i];

    if(category == obj.category || color == obj.color {
        result = true;
    }else{
        result = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `for` loop seems to be outside the ajax `success` callback. Since ajax is async, that piece of code is executed before you actually get data.

Comment: Yes the array is established first, then my ajax call, then the for loop on the original array. How should I remedy that though?

Comment: Try moving your for block right after the commented variable dump, inside the success callback

Comment: I will do that, but I'm still unsure about the syntax in the for loop. Is that correct to equate the two?

Comment: @TomN. I am guessing this is a Laravel application, seeing `{{ csrf_token() }}`. It's also jQuery. Adding the relevant tags help you get better answers.

Comment: @TomN. Not really. `category ` should be something like `data.ID.name.type[0].category`, same for color. But I can't really say because I cannot fully understand the var dump

Comment: @TomN. is this your return data object structure? `{ ID: { name: { type: { [ {category: 'qwerty', color: 'red'}, {category: 'asdfg', color: 'red'} ] } } } }`. it isn't clear from the comment in the code.

Comment: Yes that's correct, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to process the returned data within the `success()` method which is deprecated as of jQuery 3.0 and replaced by the `done()` method here.

> **Deprecation Notice**: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are removed as of jQuery 3.0. You can use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.

See full documentation [here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

The following code should meet your requirements. If not, you can easily modify it to suit your purpose.

```
var itemArray = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($items);?>');
//this contains items called 'category' and 'color'

//console.log(itemArray);
var code = document.getElementById("code").value;
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'validate',
    data:{code:code},
    _token: '{{ csrf_token() }}'
}).done(
    function(data){
        let results = []; // contains result for each item in itemArray
        $.each(itemArray, function(index1, value1) {
            let result = false;
            $.each(data.ID.name.type, function(index2, value2) {
                // both category and color must match
                // if you want either to match use OR (||) instead
                if(value1.category === value2.category && value1.color === value2.color) {
                    result = true;
                    break;
                }
            });
            results.push(result);
        });
        console.log(results); // see your results here
    }
);
```

This solutions assumes that the categories are unique and the colors are not necessarily unique. It also assumes that matches must be of same category and color. So, if you have **itemArray**:

```
[
    { category: 'cat1', color: 'red' }, 
    { category: 'cat2', color: 'white' }, 
    { category: 'cat3', color: 'blue' }
]
```

and return ajax **data**:

```
{ 
    ID: { 
        name: { 
            type: [ 
                {category: 'cat1', color: 'red'}, 
                {category: 'cat3', color: 'red'} 
            ] 
        } 
    } 
}
```

the returned **results** will be

```
[true, false, false]
```